# Handling two different Model for login through devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am having two type of user . one is customer and second is provider. so two different models for login are there .i follow the devise documentation and it is working fine . Now what i want if a customer is already logged in than provider can not be logged in or sign up until customer is sign out. so what i am trying to do allow login with one model at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can do some check in the application controller

```
if customer_is_sign_in?
  provider_sign_out
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i do not want to sign out . just want to make sure that user can not access the sign in path . yes i can put a custom before filter to check that. but what i am looking for is something that provided by devise for handling such situation